# how to center a css sprite inside a div?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I created a css sprite to combine several images appearing on my homepage. However I now have issues displaying those images.

[image]

You see that the images (store logos) are not displayed centrally. Here is my html code:

```
           <div class="slider-slick">
               <?php foreach($stores as $store){?>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="client">
                            <div class="sprite sprite-<?php echo $store->_storeName?>"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <?}?>
            </div>
```

The css for the sprite is:

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url(../images/spritesheet-logos.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: auto;
}

.sprite-store1 {
    width: 149px;
    height: 71px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}

.sprite-store2 {
    width: 148px;
    height: 23px;
    background-position: -164px -5px;
}
```

and the parent div is:

```
.client {
    padding: 70% 0 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

After removing the padding they look like:

[image]

I've been trying all different options with margin but couldn't really make it. Any ideas how to make them look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using flexbox:

```
.client {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Well not much of a difference. Actually after removing the padding they look bit better (see image). but still I need them to look like in the last img I uploaded

Comment: @panipsilos You can try adding some `height` to `.client` I think it should work.

Comment: right, using some height and width it actually worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use padding to center the inner elements with different height.

Give height to the parent and fill the bg color

```
.client {
    padding: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 71px;
}
```

and position the inner div using transform, so it will be center with any height.

```
.client > div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the sprite div, add margin: auto auto;

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your .sprite css:

```
background-position: center;
```

(I found it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp))